# SQL Cartesian product

Tags: sql

[image: screenshot]

The above results are of the second join operation below, `FactPayTransaction` and 
`FactPairingSegments` respectively.

I have two fact tables - `FactPairingSegments` and `FactPayTransactions`.

I am performing a join on these two as follows:

```
SELECT 
    ps.Bidperiod, ps.PairingNumber,
    ps.ActBlockMin, ps.ActCreditMin,
    ps.ActDeadHeadMin,
    pt.EmployeeKey, pt.TransactionKey, pt.PayCreditMin, pt.Comment
FROM 
    FactPairingSegments ps,
    FactPayTransaction pt
WHERE
    ps.Bidperiod = pt.BidPeriod
    AND ps.PairingDateKey = pt.PairingDateKey
    AND ps.PairingNumber = pt.PairingNumber
    AND pt.pairinglegnumber = ps.PairingLegNumber
```

However, this would retrieve only a subset of rows as there are a lot of rows in the `PayTransaction` table which have `PairingLegNumber = NULL`.

So I tried this with a union of previous query:

```
SELECT 
    ps.Bidperiod, ps.PairingNumber, ps.pairinglegnumber,
    pt.PairingNumber, pt.PairingLegNumber,
    ps.ActBlockMin, ps.ActCreditMin, ps.ActDeadHeadMin,
    pt.EmployeeKey, pt.TransactionKey, pt.PayCreditMin, pt.Comment
FROM 
    FactPairingSegments ps,
    FactPayTransaction pt
WHERE
    ps.Bidperiod = pt.BidPeriod
    AND ps.PairingDateKey = pt.PairingDateKey
    AND ps.PairingNumber = pt.PairingNumber
    AND pt.PairingLegNumber IS NULL
```

But this is causing a Cartesian product.

The problem I have is, the `FactPairingSegments` table does not contain the rows with NULL `PairingLegNumber`. These rows are only present in `PayTransactions`. Is there any way to avoid cross join?

Any help appreciated

Comment: I think you may find the answer if you rewrite with a `JOIN` instead of comma join.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I initially tried with the join syntax  as well but no luck.

Comment: whats the expected result? You want all rows from which table?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following.

```
SELECT ps.Bidperiod
,ps.PairingNumber
,ps.ActBlockMin
,ps.ActCreditMin
,ps.ActDeadHeadMin
,pt.EmployeeKey
,pt.TransactionKey
,pt.PayCreditMin
,pt.Comment
FROM FactPayTransaction pt
LEFT JOIN FactPairingSegments ps ON ps.Bidperiod        = pt.BidPeriod
                                AND ps.PairingDateKey   = pt.PairingDateKey
                                AND ps.PairingNumber    = pt.PairingNumber
                                AND pt.pairinglegnumber = ps.PairingLegNumber;
```

Fact tables are typically weird like that cause they have like a gajilion primary key fields and you need to join on all of them. If one of your tables is missing data you might want to consider examining the data and make sure your keys/tables/tuples are set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, guys. The issue was that I was missing out on a pairing key which is why the results were weird.

Comment: Would you be able to add a little more content to this answer. Perhaps a code snip showing what you did to correct the error?

Answer (score 0):

I added the airline key to the join condition:

```
SELECT ps.Bidperiod
,ps.PairingNumber
,ps.ActBlockMin
,ps.ActCreditMin
,ps.ActDeadHeadMin
,pt.EmployeeKey
,pt.TransactionKey
,pt.PayCreditMin
,pt.Comment
FROM FactPayTransaction pt
LEFT JOIN FactPairingSegments ps ON ps.Bidperiod        = pt.BidPeriod
                                AND ps.PairingDateKey   = pt.PairingDateKey
                                AND ps.PairingNumber    = pt.PairingNumber
                                AND pt.pairinglegnumber = ps.PairingLegNumber
                                AND pt.Airlinekey=ps.Airlinekey
```