# computation within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called factprojection which has the columns as shown in the image.

I want to multiply the 'value' column which have 'Total Lines & RSV Required'in the 'Measures' column with the 'value' column which have 'Line Average' in the 'Measures' column joining it by crew type. Should I create a temp table and then perform the multiplication? Could anyone help me with this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like there are lots of rows with the same `CrewType`, so just joining on that column will give you lots of not very meaningful results. Are you also joining by `DateKey`?

Comment: Yes, by the date key also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Cartesian product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51030829/sql-cartesian-product)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

N.B. I'm assuming all `CrewType` and `DateKey` values are in both tables, so all answers below use inner joins (any rows not matching on both sides are not returned)

## Common Table Expressions (CTEs)

You can define Common Table Expressions that perform queries on the table, and then name those queries. You can then join these 'sub-tables', rather than generating any temporary data:

```
WITH LineAverage as (
    select * 
    from factprojection
    where Measure = 'Line Average'
)
,TotalLines as (
    select * 
    from factprojection
    where Measure = 'Total Lines & RSV Required'
)
select
    LA.CrewType
    ,LA.DateKey
    ,LA.Value*TL.Value as newvalue
from LineAverage LA 
inner join
TotalLines TL
    ON LA.DateKey = TL.DateKey
    and LA.CrewType = TL.CrewType
```

## Self join

An equivalent but less visually obvious approach is a self-join, giving the tables different aliases:

```
select
    LA.CrewType
    ,LA.DateKey
    ,LA.Value*TL.Value as newvalue
from factprojection LA,
     factprojection TL
where LA.DateKey = TL.DateKey
    and LA.CrewType = TL.CrewType
    and LA.Measure = 'Line Average'
    and TL.Measure = 'Total Lines & RSV Required'
```

Notice the use of restrictions on the `Measure` values alongside the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause. Although this query is marginally shorter to write it loses some readability over the CTE approach.

Here I've also used the comma form of an `INNER JOIN`, where the `ON` clause is replaced by placing the join conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you so much!